# Extract React Router state in URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, server-side-rendering, react-router-redux

I'm using react-router and redux-simple-router in conjunction with server side rendering and when I navigate to a url like:

```
routeActions.push({ pathname: '/main', state: 'some_state'});
```

I want to be able to extract `some_state` from the request so I can render an initial redux state and send that back to the client. How do I extract the state from the request on the server side? Where does history and react-router put it?

This is particularly important for mobile because desktop, as I've tested, doesn't fire separate requests but mobile devices do which means the page reloads with a fresh initial state.

Answer (score 0):

`state` corresponds to [state in the History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) - it's associated with the current location, but it's only available on the client, so it's not suitable for passing along arbitrary data if your app needs to support server-side rendering.

If you want it to be available on the server, you would need to make it part of the URL. perhaps as a query string.

> **Aside:** location state is useful in other ways in isomorphic/universal apps, such as passing around POSTed form data to be handled using an `onEnter` hook, or for passing form data and validation errors to use a redirect transition to respond by rendering an invalid form in the same scenario.