# react-router & redux-simple-router losing state on mobile chrome refresh

Tags: javascript, react-router, html5-history, react-router-redux

Somewhat related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34861481/extract-react-router-state-in-url) I asked, I've found a rather frustrating bug/implementation detail in mobile chrome when interacting with the history api via [redux-simple-router](https://github.com/rackt/redux-simple-router) & [react router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router).

My scenario is simple; my application has several urls (made pretty using the browser history object). For the sake of example let's say they're `/` `/product`, and `/contact`. On the `/` route and the `/` route only, I have a signup form and in a header component (I'm also using React), a signup button that links directly to that signup bar.

How I've implemented this is in my top level app component I have:

```
  browserHistory.listen(location => {
  if (typeof location.state === 'undefined' || location.state === null) {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }
});
```

which on every page change, will scroll to the top of the page. However, if there's a page change and the location state is non-null, such as `signup`, nothing will happen scroll-wise. Then in the page that handles the render for my `/` route, I check the state to see if it's equal to `signup` and if it is, I scroll to the signup form component.

The navigation is achieved using the action creators from `redux-simple-router`:

```
dispatch(routeActions.push({ pathname: '/', state: 'signup' }));
```

On every mobile browser, that action works perfectly. However, on mobile chrome, each route action, whether I trigger it using an action creator or a `Link` component from react router, triggers a page refresh while it navigates and the application loses state. So if I hit the signup button, the page change is triggered and then the state is lost so when the page checks `this.props.location.state`, it's been reset to null.

Now I've tested this extensively, I have no problems on desktop Chrome, Firefox, or Safari, and the same for Firefox, Opera, and Safari on iOS. Each `routeActions.push` action triggers the page change and maintains state.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here? I've been banging my head against a wall for hours trying to figure out why it doesn't work only on Chrome on iOS. Is it simply an implementation detail of Chrome's history api? And if so, why doesn't it affect Chrome browser on desktop?

Comment: this is a wild stab in the dark... but have you tried renaming the varable to something other than `location`, given that location is an object on `window` in most browsers and therefore available in the global scope.  I know that it shouldn't matter, because are reassigning the name in the functional scope.  Its just an idea.

Comment: eg. `browserHistory.listen(loc => { /* do your thing */ })`

Comment: I'll definitely try that, thanks @eblahm

Comment: Nah didn't do anything, worth a try though

Comment: figured it out: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/2565